# Converting a vector<char *> to char ** array?

Tags: c++, vector, char

I'm trying to convert a vector<char * > into a char** array. When I print parsed[0], I get garbage. How would I fix this?

```
char **parse(vector<string> arr){
   vector<char*> res;

   for(int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++){
       string s = arr.at(i);
       char temp[s.length() + 1];
       s.copy(temp, s.length()+1);
       temp[s.length()] = '\0';

       res.push_back(temp);
   }

    res.push_back(NULL);
    char **parsed = res.data();

    cout << parsed[0] << endl; 

    return parsed; 
}
```

Comment: Do you need to make a copy of the string data, or is it sufficient to have pointers to the `c_str()` values?

Comment: `char temp[s.length() + 1];` -- This is not valid C++.

Comment: pointers to the c_str() value is ok. @tadman

Comment: `temp` is a local variable, storing a pointer to it in your vector leads to a dangling pointer

Comment: change i=0 in the loop '''for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)'''

Comment: (continuing from Alan Birtles' comment): ... and printing a dangling pointer often gives garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Just going by the title calling `vector<char*>.data()` seems to be the most straightforward way:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char*> chars{};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<char**, decltype(chars.data())>);
}
```

Comment: The OP is already using `.data()` in their code

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a really convoluted method of just doing:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::vector<const char*> to_ptrs(const std::vector<std::string>& arr) {
  std::vector<const char*> res;

  for (auto& s : arr) {
    res.emplace_back(s.c_str());
  }

  return res;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> input = {
    "test",
    "example",
    "of",
    "strings"
  };

  auto ptr_vec = to_ptrs(input); // To avoid dangling temporary
  const char** result = ptr_vec.data();

  for (size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Or if you prefer a C++20 solution with `std::transform`:

```
std::vector<const char*> to_ptrs(const std::vector<std::string>& arr) {
  std::vector<const char*> res;

  std::transform(arr.begin(), arr.end(), std::back_inserter(res), [](const std::string& s) -> const char* { return s.c_str(); });

  return res;
}
```

Note conversion to `char**` is not possible because the result of `c_str()` is `const char*`.

> Note: Any alterations to the original strings or string data invalidates these pointers.

Comment: Maybe add a caveat that the `const char *`s become invalidated if any of the `string` objects are modified?

Comment: @JaMiT Yeah, that's a good point. Fixed in an edit. As for the string pointers, I asked if that was acceptable and it was confirmed.

Comment: I don't question the acceptability. I'm suggesting that it might be good to have documentation, mostly for the next person with the same question. It's good to be aware that, for example, adding the line `input[2] += " cool";` (after calling `to_ptrs`) invalidates `result[2]`.

Comment: am I missing something or why is the transform version c++20?

Comment: " char** is not possible " sure it is. just allocate some memory and copy to it.

Comment: @PatrickParker Without that, obviously.

Comment: nothing c++20 about your c++20 solution, apart from the lambda it would work in c++03, the lambda only makes it need c++11: https://godbolt.org/z/ejKo41